# Twisted and python list concurrent access

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, twisted

i have a question with concurrent access to list in python with twisted.
I have a twisted class that adds data to a list, and a method that's called every 4 seconds. This methods it the element of the list and do some operation. 
I fear that accessing the same list both from ossPeriodic and both from dataReceived can create consistency problem.
Here is the code:

```
ossStorage=[]

def ossPeriodic():
for i in ossStorage:
            ossStorage.remove(i)
    db.insertDataToDb(i)
reactor.callLater(4, ossPeriodic)

class OSS(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        account = pickle.loads(data)        
        ossStorage.append(account)



def main():
    ossFactory = Factory()
    ossFactory.protocol = OSS
    reactor.listenTCP(50000, ossFactory)    
    reactor.callLater(4, ossPeriodic)
    reactor.run()
```

Should I use lock or something similar?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe using queue should help?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using threads?  If not then you do not have concurrent access to the list.

Typically an application using Twisted does not use threads.  Twisted's asynchronous nature executes in a single thread processing each event in sequence.  The asynchronous nature provides for concurrent-like behavior, such as handling many network connections in parallel, but each callback function runs to completion before the next one is called.

Comment: Even if he had threads (and this weren't twisted), python's GIL would protect him from anything going wrong in the above code.

Where you generally get into trouble with lists and the GIL is when you're iterating across a list, something blocks, and then some other thread modifies the list.

Comment: The GIL does not protect against concurrent access from separate threads.  The GIL only ensures that each Python opcode is run to completion, but does not ensure that a function completes.  All access (both read and write) to any shared data structure must be correctly synchronized in a threaded environment, not just iteration over the list.

Comment: I stand corrected.  It looks like Python will periodically preempt and/or switch threads periodically after executing some number of opcodes.